# arch linux wifi-menu: doesn't shows an error, but doesn't connect to the network

Tags: arch-linux, netctl

After installing arch, I wanted to set up wifi. I typed `wifi-menu wlp3s0` and selected my network. After that wifi-menu exited with no error. I typed `ping - c3 google.com` to verify my internet connection. I got `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution` I typed `wifi-menu wlp3s0` again and in front of my wireless network is a`:`(handmade profile present). But i want `*`(active connection present). Can someone help me?

Comment: Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work?

Comment: No, it says: ```ping: connect: Network is unreachable```

Comment: OK, please add that into your question since that would rule out a simple DNA issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that some packages were missing.
The packages you need are: `wireless_tools`, `wpa_supplicant`, `netctl`, `dialog`, `dhcpcd` and `dhclient`